# Customization of GridView like in the image

Tags: android, xml, grid

Please help me in customizing like in the image[image]

Below is my grid_mainborders.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/grid_two_borderselected"
        /> <!-- focused -->
    <item  android:state_focused="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/grid_two_bordernormal"/>

    </selector>
```

Below is my grid_two_borderselected.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />
    <padding android:left="7dp" android:top="7dp"
        android:right="7dp" android:bottom="7dp" />
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
</shape>
```

Below is my grid_two_bordernormal.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <padding android:left="7dp" android:top="7dp"
        android:right="7dp" android:bottom="7dp" />
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
</shape>
```

Below is my GridView Item file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/grid_mainborders">



<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/cardViewGridLangsItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/grid_mainborders">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMaintext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="English"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSubText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="English"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:padding="5dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAlphabet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="E"
            android:textSize="38sp"
            android:padding="5dp"/>


    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</FrameLayout>
```

I am using gridview with base adapter,
I have tried with few links but almost background is changing not with the corners.
Please help me on this Thanks in advance

Comment: post your code here

Comment: I have added my files.Please check

Comment: Do you want only one item as selectable with cutom border in recyclerView at a time or multiple selection  ?

Comment: What exactly does not work with your approach?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create shape something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/boardersshape"
        /> <!-- focused -->
    <item  android:state_focused="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/boarder"/>

</selector>
```

boardersshape codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/homebackground" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

boarder codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/silver" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Hi Mohammad, Thanks for your response, where to add the selector XML ?I am confused

Comment: Right-click on drawble. Then tap drawble resource file and then create a selector.

Comment: Means should I add this selector XML to Gridview or GridItem Layout ?

Comment: you have to add in griditem layout

Answer (score -1):

First of all, I am not the coding police, but maybe have a look in newer versions/replacements of your components, if you have free time. They will save you a ton of time.
Like
[Recylcerview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#workflow) or
[GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/GridLayoutManager)

Anyway. You were almost there.
Use following code for your griditem.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardViewGridLangsItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/selectable_background">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="0.4dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvMaintext"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="English"
                    android:textSize="26sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvSubText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="English"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvAlphabet"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="E"
                    android:textSize="38sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And add a new `selectable_background.xml` in your `res/drawable` folder with following code:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

You can now set your selection via your adapter. But, as I already said, try to use newer components.

[image: result]

Answer (score -2):

This might help you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardViewGridLangsItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/selectable_background">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="0.4dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvMaintext"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="English"
                    android:textSize="26sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvSubText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="English"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvAlphabet"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="E"
                    android:textSize="38sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Did you really just copy parts of my answer without any modification?